# Can't click the login button on this website by using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Everyone,

I would like to browse the following website by using Selenium.

https://www.kintips.com/tc/kintips-app.html

(please select "ENG" if you can only read English.)

Here is what I wanted to do:

1. Open the website with Edge.
2. Click the "User Login" button.
3. Enter ID and password.
4. Click "Login".

I was stuck at Step 2. I tried many strategies like `find_element_by_class_name` and `find_element_by_css_selector`. But all the responses were "no such element: Unable to locate element".

How do I locate the element for "User Login" button? Please help. Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Edge()

#step 1
browser.get('https://kintips.com/tc/kintips-app.html')

#step 2, click a button
current = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('button-inner')
```

Answer (score 1):

The login button is contained in a `iframe` webelement (to view it open the browser inspector tool and search `//iframe`) that's why it gives you the error "no such element: Unable to locate element". First you have to switch to the iframe, and then you can find the element, as shown in the code below

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Edge()

browser.get('https://kintips.com/tc/kintips-app.html')

# pause 30 seconds to let the page load fully, you can reduce or increase this value to your needs
time.sleep(30)

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='iads001']")))
login_button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class*='login']")
login_button.click()
```

Comment: You codes solve the problem and help me with the rest of the steps. Thank you.